# I would like to have a clarification about Python's issubset method

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

I have this snippet:

```
DNA = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'N']
sequence = ''
set(sequence.upper()).issubset(DNA)
```

And I have a `True` in response. I would like a clarification why? Since `''` is not part of `DNA`. The docs says: If the iterable is empty, returns `False`.

Comment: Please tag all python-related questions with the generic [python] tag. you can use version specific tags at your discretion, generally, Python 3 is assumed nowadays

Answer (score 5):

`set(sequence.upper())` is `set()` (the empty set), and the empty set is a subset of every set.

And from the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset):

> **`issubset(other)`**
>   **`set <= other`**
>   Test whether every element in the set is in other.
>
> **`set < other`**
>   Test whether the set is a proper subset of other, that is, `set <= other` and `set != other`.

Comment: forgot the basic math.